# Spring Configuration

Tags: xml, spring

I've been reading up on Spring and it keeps talking about the spring configuration data you need, but where do you put this xml file? and what do you save it as? I can't seem to find this information anywhere.

Comment: Are you using Spring inside something like Tomcat, or are you making a stand-alone application? How is your application being launched?

Comment: these tutorials are useful when learning spring http://krams915.blogspot.com/p/tutorials.html

Answer (score 10):

More importantly than where, the question should be for you: what exactly is this 'configuration data'?

From the [docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-metadata):

> the Spring IoC container consumes a form of configuration metadata; this configuration metadata represents how you as an application developer tell the Spring container to instantiate, configure, and assemble the objects in your application.
>
> Configuration metadata is traditionally supplied in a simple and intuitive XML format, which is what most of this chapter uses to convey key concepts and features of the Spring IoC container.

However, you can also use [annotations](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-annotation-config) or [Java-based configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java) to provide the configuration metadata for your POJOs.

> In Spring, the objects that form the backbone of your application and that are managed by the Spring IoC container are called beans. A bean is an object that is instantiated, assembled, and otherwise managed by a Spring IoC container. Otherwise, a bean is simply one of many objects in your application. Beans, and the dependencies among them, are reflected in the configuration metadata used by a container.

As Tnem already mentioned, [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-instantiation) you can find how to instantiate a container in different scenarios.

And what is this IoC container?

IoC (inversion of control) and DI (dependency injection) are terms coined by [Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html), regarding Spring see the [first section of the docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#overview-dependency-injection).

I encourage you to read the whole reference if you want to get into development with Spring.

Comment: I also find quite difficult find reference on configuration files naming in spring web application. The reference keep talking about the content of the "beans" file, but not a word on its name. Reading around i found that it has a CoC behavior: it looks first for a file called applicationContext.xml. Then it looks into the web.xml context parameters. Searching the reference, the word "CoC" is never mentioned. I would like to come up with a definitive response on this topic.

Comment: @AgostinoX: The name of the XML file is not important - the content is. Spring lets You name the configuration files anyway You find convinient - that's why the name of the configuration files are never mentioned in the docs. Generally I agree with @abalogh that first You have to decide `how` You want to configure it, and than `where` to put the configuration metadata. The `applicationContext.xml` is just a simple default name of the configuration file if You don't pass any custom ones, but it doesn't mean You have to use this name.

Comment: @AgostinoX: If You're looking for best practices in naming and placing spring configuration files - well, I don't know if there are any, and if so, IMHO this question doesn't ask for it. I recently found that for OSGi the classpath location `META-INF/spring/*.xml` is the default one. I liked it and started to use it in my non-OSGi apps too. I also use naming conventions to easily divide my config files into groups using expressions (i.e. `META-INF/spring/*-context.xml`, `META-INF/spring/*-webcontext.xml`, `META-INF/spring/*-testcontext.xml`).

Comment: @Roadrunner: unfortunately the question here is exactly about the file name. I know the content very very well because i've read all the reference and other books about the content, but want a word of clarity about the name too.

Comment: @AgostinoX: the name and location of your configuration files are entirely up to you.

Comment: Some of the links seem to be broken.

Answer (score 8):

More interesting than the pure name is how do you split the files (and give each part a name).

If you have a Standalone or Webapplication with out tests, then you can put all configuration in one file. - But having no test should not be a opinion.

Lets assume you have a web application with tests.

Then you should split the configuration in two files, one for the pure java (without the web suff) configuration and one that contains all the other stuff for the WEB application.

I personaly perfer to name it applicationContext.xml and webmvc-config.xml.
*The default name for the web configuration file (if no specifed for the Dispatcher Servlet) would be `/WEB-INF/<servletname>-servlet.xml`)*

I locate the applicationContext.xml in `classpath:/META-INF/spring` directory and the webmvc-config.xml in `WEB-INF/spring`. That location is the style of Spring Roo. It works, but every other folder would work too. Because I use maven the exact location of the files are:

- `/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml`
- `/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml`

The core applicationContext.xml is loaded with the `org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener`, and the webmvc-config.xml by the Dispatacher Servlet. `web.xml`:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CFMA-SpringProject</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Now you start to write your tests, for the business logic of your application, without loading all the web stuff. But in most cases that is not enougth. For example you want to run some fast tests with an Inmemory Database while you run the normal Application with an persistent Database like MySql (*please don't blame me for that sentence*), or you want to use a jndi configured db in production and a "normal" configured one for tests. So what you need is two different configuration. To write not every thing twice, the easiest way is to split the `applicationContext.xml` in two files:

- `applicationContext.xml` for the core stuff without the db stuff that differs to the tests
- `applicationContext-db.xml` for the productive db configuration (for example jndi-lookup for db connection and LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean for MySql)

(*Now you understand the pattern of `contextConfigLocation` in the web.xml*)

For the Tests you need now two files (you can write it in one file, but I prefer two).
 * `testContext-h2DbConfig.xml` The file that is the testing sibling of `applicationContext-db.xml`, but with the test database and without jndi.
 * `textContext.xml` This file in the one referenced by `@ContextConfiguration` in you test cases. This file contains only the imports of the configuration you need for the tests. In this case it is:

```
<import resource="classpath:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml" /> 
<import resource="classpath:/META-INF/spring/testContext-h2DbConfig.xml" />
```

Because I use spring, both files are located in `/src/test/resources/META-INF/spring/testContext.xml`

If you have other aspects of your spring configuration, where the test and the productive configuration differs (for example schedulers), then you can split it in the same way.

I hope you understand how splitting, naming convention and location work together.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if there is an "official" name at all, then I guess it should come from the Spring guys themselves. And Spring's tool of choice to set up conformant Spring projects is Roo, looking [there](http://www.springsource.org/roo/guide?w=beginning) we find `SRC_MAIN_RESOURCES/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml` (with `SRC_MAIN_RESOURCES` being a placehiolder for `src/main/resources` in a Maven2 project).

Comment: +1 for telling me where to put the `applicationContext.xml` file in a standalone app using Maven!

Answer (score 0):

It depends what your application is, some applications support the configuration of Spring, in this case you will need to check that frameworks documentation.

If it is a standalone application then you can put the file anywhere, but generally it is placed in

```
src/main/resources
```

or a subdirectory in `resources`.

Section 3.2.2 of the Spring [docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html) shows u how to instantiate the `ApplicationContext`.

Comment: `src/main/resources` is only for maven built projects

Comment: @aseychell Yes true, wow im so entrenched in my maven ways :D

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out the name of the Spring configuration file is not very important. The real question is how this file is loaded.
In a standalone application you do it explicitly by using something like the ClassPathXmlApplicationContext class, as described in [this part of the Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-app-ctx).

In a web application this is usually configured in the web.xml file, by adding definitions for configuration listeners, and possibly configuration files. This is the setup I use:

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:appContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
<listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

This allows me to put the config file anywhere I like, as long as it's on the application's classpath. You can even specify several configuration files in the param-value element, by separating them with spaces.