# XML files needed to configure Spring application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I want to know the best practice of configuring Spring XML configuration files

1- how many configuration files should I have ?
2- contents of each file.

Right now, I have 3 xml configuration files for my Spring application, based on some tutorial:

1- app-config.xml:  which contains the propertyPlaceholder configuration, and hibernate configuration, and following annotation configuration.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.sample" />

    <!-- declares support for general annotations such as @Required, @Autowired,         @PostConstruct -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

2- mvc-config.xml: which contains annotation support tag, messageSource configuration, mvc interceptor, and localResolver

3- servlet-config.xml: which contains the viewResolver for jsp, and the following tag:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.sample.controller"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this answer. [Spring Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6283653/spring-configuration/6902999#6902999)

You layout is good, the answer will explain why I use a similar.

Comment: nice post, but i have two questions: 1- why do you use * here: <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>                                                                2- why do you use the tag  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> with the DispatcherServlet

Comment: 1: because i ofte split a projet in different jars. 2 oh it seams to be the left ovet from an older application or a spring roo default. - I can not answer this without my Pc. (I am in holiday and have only my smart phone)